# Folder Copy Error:System.UnauthorizedAccessException in C#

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks

I want to copy an existing file to another destination, but it gives an access error.

```
Error Name:
System.UnauthorizedAccessException
```

I understand that I need to grant access but I don't know how to do this.

My project looks like:
[image]

I will put the file on the server and run this program from the web-based program. I will close the button and textbox with the source file. I will only leave the target forms open

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

            worker.ProgressChanged += Worker_ProgressChanged;
            worker.DoWork += Worker_DoWork;

        }

        void Copyfile(string source, string des)
        {
            FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(des, FileMode.Create);
            FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(source, FileMode.Open);
            byte[] bt = new byte[1048456];
            int readByte;
            while ((readByte = fsIn.Read(bt, 0, bt.Length)) > 0)
            {
                fsOut.Write(bt,0,readByte);
                worker.ReportProgress((int)(fsIn.Position * 100 / fsIn.Length));
            }
            fsIn.Close();
            fsOut.Close();
        }
        private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            Copyfile(txtSource.Text, txtTarget.Text);
        }
        private void Worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            label1.Text = progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "%";
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            FolderBrowserDialog fbd1 = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            if (fbd1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                txtSource.Text = Path.Combine(fbd1.SelectedPath, Path.GetFileName(txtTarget.Text));
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                txtTarget.Text = Path.Combine(fbd.SelectedPath, Path.GetFileName(txtSource.Text));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try running as admin

Comment: I'm assuming there must be a reason for not using File.Copy() ?

Comment: I changed level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" to level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" on app.manifest file but still not working

Comment: 3 more things to try
1. Right click the folder and check the security tab and verify the permissions, modify the rights for the user your app runs under
2. If your using IIS check if IIS have the right permissions
3. Check and set the file attributes Example: `File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);`

Comment: @Clint  I wrote a file (sorry about that) but I am trying to copy a folder and all subdirectories of the folder

Comment: Which means, your copying a folder and its subdirectories and/or files it may contain, correct ?

Comment: @Clint Yes,exactly

Comment: cool, the error is to do with permissions issue, did you verify the 3 steps that I mentioned earlier, pls double check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added and changed some codes

```
public static void CopyAll(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(target.FullName);
            // HER DOSYAYI YENI DIZINE KOPYALAR
            foreach (FileInfo fi in source.GetFiles())
            {
                fi.CopyTo(System.IO.Path.Combine(target.FullName, fi.Name), true);
            }
            // HER ALT DIZINI KOPYALAR
            foreach (DirectoryInfo diSourceSubDir in source.GetDirectories())
            {
                DirectoryInfo nextTargetSubDir =
                target.CreateSubdirectory(diSourceSubDir.Name);
                CopyAll(diSourceSubDir, nextTargetSubDir);
            }
        }

        void CopyFile(string source, string des)
        {
            FileStream fsout = new FileStream(des, FileMode.Create);
            FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(source, FileMode.Open);
            byte[] bt = new byte[1048756];
            int readByte;
            while ((readByte=fsIn.Read(bt,  0,  bt.Length))>0)
            {
                fsout.Write(bt, 0, readByte);
                worker.ReportProgress((int)(fsIn.Position*100/fsIn.Length));
            }
            fsIn.Close();
            fsout.Close();
        }
        private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            CopyAll(new DirectoryInfo( txtSource.Text), new DirectoryInfo(txtTarget.Text));
        }
```

I add my github repository:https://github.com/yusufcelik1/Copy-Folder.git